# What does reusing the name of a file mean, for an immutable file?

Tags: files

Operating System Concepts says

> A unique approach is that of immutable shared ﬁles. Once a ﬁle is
>   declared as shared by its creator, it cannot be modiﬁed. An immutable
>   ﬁle has two key properties: **its name may not be reused**, and its
>   contents may not be altered. Thus, **the name of an immutable ﬁle
>   signiﬁes that the contents of the ﬁle are ﬁxed.**

What does it mean by

- "its name may not be reused" and
- "the name of an immutable ﬁle signiﬁes that the contents of the ﬁle are ﬁxed"?

Thanks.

Comment: A unique approach...to what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You totally left out the context of the text you quoted, so I had to google it. The name must not be reused means that no other file (with different contents) gets the name, thus the name is uniquely associated with the file. The immutable and unique name represents the immutable contents of the file now and forever.

Comment: Thanks. "no other file (with different contents) gets the name" do you mean no two files having the same pathname? It is already impossible for pathname, correct. Then why is it needed to require that again?

Comment: The name cannot be reused even if the original file is deleted.